# Pre fill a form on redirection

Tags: html, web

I am working on a website which handles users' data including username and password of their subsidiary websites. I want to redirect to those websites' login page with their username and password prefilled ( which I have ). Is there any way to implement this?
I googled for this and I got an answer like

```
http://example.com/login-form/?user_name=abc&password=xyz
```

where `username` and `password` are name of html input fields

But it doesn't work.

Any attempt to help will be appreciated.

Comment: The page at `example.com` would need code which gets those values from the query string and puts them in the login form.  By the way, putting a username and password on the query string is a ***very bad idea***.  This is being grossly irresponsible with your users' passwords.

Comment: You need PHP for this job. The above method uses the $_GET field. But as mentioned before, this method is VERY insecure. Anyone could just read password and username from the URL. What if the user shares the login link? Ooops... I'll try to show a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible while still relatively secure way is probably to use sessions. Somewhere on your website you set a session variable, and somewhere else you retrieve the content. E.g. like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["username"] = "Someone";
?>
```

And on another page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!--HTML markup, not that interesting...-->
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>">
```

But this still isn't 100 % secure. HTTPS would be even more secure, but in general remember: Comfort always reduces security, security always reduces comfort. Your data is unencrypted and might get read out of the data transfer.